# What (standardized) naming is enough to completely specify a type of steel?

Tags: steel, standards

What (standardized) naming is enough to completely specify a type of steel? That is, the composition and properties.

Take for example 1.0037 S235JR. Are these two numbers linked/equivalent, do you need both? Where could I find the exact composition, is this defined or does it differ per factory?

Comment: "exact composition"? even batches vary.

Comment: Composition isn't the only thing that affects properties either.

Comment: ASTM gives a pretty complete description , although one may need to specify a grade ( eg alloy and/or strength.

Comment: When you say "complete" it implies many specifics like; fine grain practice, toughness , thermomechanical history ( such as  age hardening of micro alloyed steels.).

Comment: "complete" is not a specification level of detail.  These things will be different in different parts of the world.

Comment: The examples you mentioned specify steel composition (within some tolerances), but for "full" properties, it is better to specify a prefabricate, e.g. "Tube - 168,3 x 100 - EN 10216-2 - P195GH - TC1". Beside the material, there is also type of prefabricate with dimensions and a prefabricate standard which specifies additional things like tolerances and you can also specify the heat treatment.